# Why would long running select queries cause a replication lag in MySQL slave database?

Tags: mysql

we have a MySQL with a replica (5.7 with row based replication).

Now, the master performs at peak about 3000 inserts per second, and the replica seems to read that just fine. However, sometimes we execute long-time select queries (that ran from 10 to 20 seconds). And during those queries the replication lag becomes very huge.

What I do not understand is how the usual mysql threads that execute selects (without locking any tables) can cause the replication thread to slow down (i.e. it performs about 2.5K inserts instead of 3K like master)? What would I need to tune exactly?

Now I checked the slave status and it's not about the IO thread - this one manages to read events from the master just fine. It's SQL slave thread, that somehow does not manage to catch up. The isolation level is Read Committed, so the select queries potentially could lock some records and make the slave thread wait. But I'm not sure about that.

**UPDATED**. I have checked again - it turns out that even a single heavy query (that scans the entire table for example) on the slave produces the lag. It seems like slave sql thread is blocked, but I do not understand why?

**UPDATED 2**. I finally found the solution. First I increased number of slave_parallel_workers to 4 and set slave_parallel_type to LOGICAL_CLOCK. However, **and this is important**, that gave me no improvement at all, since the transactions were dependent. But, after I increased on master binlog_group_commit_sync_delay to 10000 (that is, 10 milliseconds), the lag disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

There Might be many reasons why replication lag in mysql slave database.
But as you mentioned

> It's SQL slave thread, that somehow does not manage to catch up.

Assuming that IO works fine, [Percona](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/05/02/how-to-identify-and-cure-mysql-replication-slave-lag/) says (emphasis mine):

> [...] when the slave SQL_THREAD is the source of replication delays it is probably because of queries coming from the replication stream are taking too long to execute on the slave. This is sometimes because of different hardware between master/slave, different schema indexes, workload. Moreover, the slave OLTP workload sometimes causes replication delays because of locking.
>  **For instance, if a long-running read against a MyISAM table blocks the SQL thread, or any transaction against an InnoDB table creates an IX lock and blocks DDL in the SQL thread. Also, take into account that slave is single threaded prior to MySQL 5.6, which would be another reason for delays on the slave SQL_THREAD**.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I finally found a solution myself. See my edited post